# Mule 4.2 - DWL 2.0 - After Result of groupBy need to remove groupBy

Tags: json, mule, mule4

I need to remove groupBy field and its value from actual data after performing groupBy Operation in DWL 2.0.

For Example

I have payload with json array like:

```
[
  {
    "empId": 1,
    "empName": "James",
    "deptName": "Sales"
  },
  {
    "empId": 2,
    "empName": "ABC",
    "deptName": "Marketing"
  },
  {
    "empId": 3,
    "empName": "BCD",
    "deptName": "Account"
  },
  {
    "empId": 4,
    "empName": "EFG",
    "deptName": "Sales"
  },
  {
    "empId": 5,
    "empName": "HIJK",
    "deptName": "Account"
  },
  {
    "empId": 6,
    "empName": "LMN",
    "deptName": "Sales"
  },
  {
    "empId": 7,
    "empName": "OPQR",
    "deptName": "Marketing"
  }
]
```

On this added transformation to perform groupBy -->

```
<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message">
    <ee:message>
        <ee:set-payload>
        <![CDATA[%dw 2.0
                    output
                    application/json
                    ---                 
                    (payload groupBy (item) -> item.customerId) 
         ]]></ee:set-payload>
    </ee:message>
</ee:transform>
```

And Result of this transformation is -->

```
{
  "Sales": [
    {
      "empId": 1,
      "empName": "James",
      "deptName": "Sales"
    },
    {
      "empId": 4,
      "empName": "EFG",
      "deptName": "Sales"
    },
    {
      "empId": 6,
      "empName": "LMN",
      "deptName": "Sales"
    }
  ],
  "Marketing": [
    {
      "empId": 2,
      "empName": "ABC",
      "deptName": "Marketing"
    },
    {
      "empId": 7,
      "empName": "OPQR",
      "deptName": "Marketing"
    }
  ],
  "Account": [
    {
      "empId": 3,
      "empName": "BCD",
      "deptName": "Account"
    },
    {
      "empId": 5,
      "empName": "HIJK",
      "deptName": "Account"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when you look at the result depetName tag is no longer needed in actual data json. i want to remove this element from data json and wanted final result like -->

```
{
  "Sales": [
    {
      "empId": 1,
      "empName": "James"
    },
    {
      "empId": 4,
      "empName": "EFG"
    },
    {
      "empId": 6,
      "empName": "LMN"
    }
  ],
  "Marketing": [
    {
      "empId": 2,
      "empName": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "empId": 7,
      "empName": "OPQR"
    }
  ],
  "Account": [
    {
      "empId": 3,
      "empName": "BCD"
    },
    {
      "empId": 5,
      "empName": "HIJK"
    }
  ]
}
```

Could any one help me out to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mapObject function to remap the result of the groupBy and then map the value group result and remove the field in each object

```
output application/json
---                 
payload groupBy ((item) -> item.deptName) 
        mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
            {
                (key): value map ((item, index) -> item - "deptName")
            })
```